# Re-size a rotated rectangle using mouse drag in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, math

It will seems to most of the guys here that it's a repeated question but it isn't.

I am having a very hard problem. I have a rectangle which can be re-sized when it's not rotated and all work fine. But when it's rotated the algorithm is not working. The code is below:

```
internal void resizeToPoint(int tmpX, int tmpY, Rectangle limits)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.Reset();

    m.Translate(mLayoutRectangle.X + mParent.getAbsXOffset(DEPTH_LEVEL.APA) + mLayoutRectangle.Width / 2, mLayoutRectangle.Y + mParent.getAbsYOffset(DEPTH_LEVEL.APA) + mLayoutRectangle.Height / 2);
    m.Rotate(-(int)mAngle);
    m.Translate(-(mLayoutRectangle.X + mParent.getAbsXOffset(DEPTH_LEVEL.APA) + mLayoutRectangle.Width / 2), -(mLayoutRectangle.Y + mParent.getAbsYOffset(DEPTH_LEVEL.APA) + mLayoutRectangle.Height / 2));

    Point pPrime = new Point();
    pPrime.X = (int)((m.Elements[0] * tmpX + m.Elements[2] * tmpY) + (int)m.Elements[4]);
    pPrime.Y = (int)((m.Elements[1] * tmpX + m.Elements[3] * tmpY) + (int)m.Elements[5]);

    Point BottomRight = new Point(mLayoutRectangle.Width + getAbsXOffset(), mLayoutRectangle.Height + getAbsYOffset());
    Point TopRight = new Point(mLayoutRectangle.Width + getAbsXOffset(), getAbsYOffset());
    Point TopLeft = new Point(getAbsXOffset(), getAbsYOffset());
    Point BottomLeft = new Point(getAbsXOffset(), mLayoutRectangle.Height + getAbsYOffset());

    Point TopMiddle = new Point((mLayoutRectangle.Width / 2) + getAbsXOffset(), getAbsYOffset());
    Point RightMiddle = new Point(mLayoutRectangle.Width + getAbsXOffset(), mLayoutRectangle.Height / 2 + getAbsYOffset());
    Point BottomMiddle = new Point(getAbsXOffset() + mLayoutRectangle.Width / 2, mLayoutRectangle.Height + getAbsYOffset());
    Point LeftMiddle = new Point(getAbsXOffset(), getAbsYOffset() + mLayoutRectangle.Width / 2);

    Rectangle newLocationRectangle = mLayoutRectangle;
    Double widthRatioHeight = 1;

    if (this is ImageDesignElement)
    {
        widthRatioHeight = (double)((ImageDesignElement)this).getMonochromeImage().Width / (double)((ImageDesignElement)this).getMonochromeImage().Height;
        //widthRatioHeight = (double)mLayoutRectangle.Width / (double)mLayoutRectangle.Height;
    }

    int rectangleOldWidth = newLocationRectangle.Width;
    int rectangleOldHeight = newLocationRectangle.Height;
    int rectangleOldX = newLocationRectangle.X;
    int rectangleOldY = newLocationRectangle.Y;


    switch (mSelectedHandleForScaling)
    {
        case HANDLE_TYPE.TOP_LEFT:
            if (newLocationRectangle.Height - (pPrime.Y - TopLeft.Y) > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Height -= (pPrime.Y - TopLeft.Y);
                newLocationRectangle.Y += (pPrime.Y - TopLeft.Y);
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            if (newLocationRectangle.Width - (pPrime.X - TopLeft.X) > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Width -= (pPrime.X - TopLeft.X);
                newLocationRectangle.X += (pPrime.X - TopLeft.X);
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            break;

        case HANDLE_TYPE.TOP_MIDDLE:
            if (newLocationRectangle.Height - (pPrime.Y - TopMiddle.Y) > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Height -= (pPrime.Y - TopMiddle.Y);
                newLocationRectangle.Y += (pPrime.Y - TopMiddle.Y);
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            break;

        case HANDLE_TYPE.TOP_RIGHT:
            if (newLocationRectangle.Height - (pPrime.Y - TopRight.Y) > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Height -= (pPrime.Y - TopRight.Y);
                newLocationRectangle.Y += (pPrime.Y - TopRight.Y);
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            if (newLocationRectangle.Width + pPrime.X - TopRight.X > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Width += pPrime.X - TopRight.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            break;

        case HANDLE_TYPE.RIGHT_MIDDLE:

            if (newLocationRectangle.Width + pPrime.X - RightMiddle.X > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Width += pPrime.X - RightMiddle.X;
            }
            mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
            mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            break;

        case HANDLE_TYPE.BOTTOM_RIGHT:
            if (newLocationRectangle.Height + pPrime.Y - BottomRight.Y > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Height += pPrime.Y - BottomRight.Y;
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            if (newLocationRectangle.Width + pPrime.X - BottomRight.X > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Width += pPrime.X - BottomRight.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }

            break;

        case HANDLE_TYPE.BOTTOM_MIDDLE:
            if (newLocationRectangle.Height + pPrime.Y - BottomMiddle.Y > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Height += pPrime.Y - BottomMiddle.Y;
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            break;

        case HANDLE_TYPE.BOTTOM_LEFT:
            if (newLocationRectangle.Height + pPrime.Y - BottomLeft.Y > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Height += pPrime.Y - BottomLeft.Y;
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            if (newLocationRectangle.Width - (pPrime.X - BottomLeft.X) > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Width -= (pPrime.X - BottomLeft.X);
                newLocationRectangle.X += (pPrime.X - BottomLeft.X);
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            break;

        case HANDLE_TYPE.LEFT_MIDDLE:
            if (newLocationRectangle.Width - (pPrime.X - BottomLeft.X) > 0)
            {
                newLocationRectangle.Width -= (pPrime.X - BottomLeft.X);
                newLocationRectangle.X += (pPrime.X - BottomLeft.X);
                mInitialScalePoint.X = pPrime.X;
                mInitialScalePoint.Y = pPrime.Y;
            }
            break;
    }

    if (((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != Keys.Shift) && this is ImageDesignElement)
    {

        int hightChange = newLocationRectangle.Height - rectangleOldHeight;
        int widthChange = newLocationRectangle.Width - rectangleOldWidth;

        newLocationRectangle.Width = rectangleOldWidth;//reset to the old Width before the call of this method
        newLocationRectangle.Width += (int)(((double)hightChange) * widthRatioHeight); //use the difference is width to adjust Width

        if (mSelectedHandleForScaling == HANDLE_TYPE.TOP_LEFT || mSelectedHandleForScaling == HANDLE_TYPE.BOTTOM_LEFT)
        {
            newLocationRectangle.X = rectangleOldX + (rectangleOldWidth - newLocationRectangle.Width);
        }

    }

    if (this is ImageDesignElement)
    {
        mLayoutRectangle = newLocationRectangle;
        //Console.WriteLine("* mLayoutRectangle.Width =" + mLayoutRectangle.Width + " mLayoutRectangle.Height =" + mLayoutRectangle.Height);

    }
    else
    {
        mLayoutRectangle = newLocationRectangle;
    }
}
```

Now, here we have a `mLayoutRectangle` a rectangle object in which some corners can be dragged with new position `tmpX` and `tmpY` through mouse. `mAngle` is the angle in degree rotated.

The problem is when **angle is between 0 and 80** it works fine but when the angle is greater than this its behavior is changed totally. I don't get what I am doing wrong here.

I have used the following rectangle datatype: [Rectangle Structure from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx). I want to set the left, right, top and bottom values for this rectangle. Can i somehow extend it, so that i can set values for left, right, top and bottom???

The problem is well explained here: but i have to do that in window form not WPF.
[Exact explanation of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091137/scaling-of-a-rotated-element?rq=1)

Comment: How is the behaviour different above 80'?

Comment: it isn't working like normal some time where it should increase the size it actually decreases it.

Comment: does the angle treshold you observe depend on the aspect ratio of the rectangle?

Comment: not actually but the position is changed for every corner and it isn't working right as code are written for a fixed positions also its x and y is fixed and when top left comes to bottom the code for top left must not be called. i dont get the idea to generalize this code

Comment: is `m.Rotate()` expecting degrees or radians? It looks like you're give it Degrees. Its not clear what technology you're using; you may want to tag with `WPF` or `Windows.Forms`

Comment: no it takes in degrees. you can see it in the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7dwd0wc(v=vs.110).aspx
its winforms i have added the tag now. in WPF i have got the solution posted already in the question.

Comment: A github repo with sample to demonstrate the issue would be great

Comment: I've been looking at this for a while and you really need to post a [mcve]

Comment: sorry for commenting late.. actually all i want is to drag a rectangle corners to some point by mouse and it accordingly re size whether or not its rotated. The problem i am facing is when rectangle is rotated then the corner locations are changed. eg top left at 90 angle comes at top right point. then i should change the x and y location of rectangle. how can i with a little code get this done?

Comment: Honestly it is very difficult to understand your problem. Something to clarify. Scaling is different from dragging a corner of a rectangle and the corner follows the mouse cursor. In scaling it doesn't matter where the mouse is. Only the precentage and increase-decrease

Comment: you are right i just want to drag the corner of rectangle such that its height and width maintain the same ratio.how can i achieved this? and lets forget about scaling

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1: Add a blank Windows Form

2: Add Mouse handlers for `Paint`, `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseMove`

3: Add AnchorPoint.cs:

```
public enum AnchorPoint
{
    TopLeft,
    TopRight,
    BottomLeft,
    BottomRight,
    Rotation,
    Center
}
```

4: add MatrixExtension.cs

```
public static class MatrixExtension
{
    public static PointF TransformPoint(this Matrix @this, PointF point)
    {
        var points = new[] { point };

        @this.TransformPoints(points);

        return points[0];
    }
}
```

5: Edit Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool _drag;

        private SizeF _dragSize;
        private PointF _dragStart;
        private PointF _dragStartOffset;
        private RectangleF _dragRect;
        private AnchorPoint _dragAnchor;
        private Single _dragRot;

        private RectangleF _rect;
        private PointF _rectPos;
        private Single _rectRotation;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Center location of our item
            _rectPos = new PointF(200, 200);

            //The rectangle dimensions in _rectPos space
            _rect = new RectangleF(-40, -30, 80, 60);

            _rectRotation = 0;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var gc = e.Graphics;

            // Move Graphics handler to Rectangle's space
            var mat = new Matrix();
            mat.Translate(_rectPos.X, _rectPos.Y);
            mat.Rotate(_rectRotation);
            gc.Transform = mat;

            // All out gizmo rectangles are defined in Rectangle Space
            var rectTopLeft = new RectangleF(_rect.Left - 5f, _rect.Top - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectTopRight = new RectangleF(_rect.Left + _rect.Width - 5f, _rect.Top - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectBottomLeft = new RectangleF(_rect.Left - 5f, _rect.Top + _rect.Height - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectBottomRight = new RectangleF(_rect.Left + _rect.Width - 5f, _rect.Top + _rect.Height - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectRotate = new RectangleF(-5, _rect.Top + -30, 10f, 10f);
            var rectCenter = new RectangleF(-5, -5, 10f, 10f);

            var backBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.CadetBlue);
            var cornerBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.OrangeRed);

            // Looks rotated because we've transformed the graphics context
            gc.FillRectangle(backBrush, _rect);
            gc.FillRectangle(cornerBrush, rectTopLeft);
            gc.FillRectangle(cornerBrush, rectTopRight);
            gc.FillRectangle(cornerBrush, rectBottomLeft);
            gc.FillRectangle(cornerBrush, rectBottomRight);
            gc.FillRectangle(cornerBrush, rectRotate);
            gc.FillRectangle(cornerBrush, rectCenter);

            // Reset Graphics state
            gc.ResetTransform();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Compute a Screen to Rectangle transform 

            var mat = new Matrix();
            mat.Translate(_rectPos.X, _rectPos.Y);
            mat.Rotate(_rectRotation);
            mat.Invert();

            // Mouse point in Rectangle's space. 
            var point = mat.TransformPoint(new PointF(e.X, e.Y));

            var rect = _rect;
            var rectTopLeft = new RectangleF(_rect.Left - 5f, _rect.Top - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectTopRight = new RectangleF(_rect.Left + _rect.Width - 5f, _rect.Top - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectBottomLeft = new RectangleF(_rect.Left - 5f, _rect.Top + _rect.Height - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectBottomRight = new RectangleF(_rect.Left + _rect.Width - 5f, _rect.Top + _rect.Height - 5f, 10f, 10f);
            var rectRotate = new RectangleF(-5, _rect.Top + -30, 10f, 10f);

            if (!_drag)
            {
                //We're in Rectangle space now, so its simple box-point intersection test
                if (rectTopLeft.Contains(point))
                {
                    _drag = true;
                    _dragStart = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);
                    _dragAnchor = AnchorPoint.TopLeft;
                    _dragRect = new RectangleF(_rect.Left, _rect.Top, _rect.Width, _rect.Height);
                }
                else if (rectTopRight.Contains(point))
                {
                    _drag = true;
                    _dragStart = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);
                    _dragAnchor = AnchorPoint.TopRight;
                    _dragRect = new RectangleF(_rect.Left, _rect.Top, _rect.Width, _rect.Height);
                }
                else if (rectBottomLeft.Contains(point))
                {
                    _drag = true;
                    _dragStart = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);
                    _dragAnchor = AnchorPoint.BottomLeft;
                    _dragRect = new RectangleF(_rect.Left, _rect.Top, _rect.Width, _rect.Height);
                }
                else if (rectBottomRight.Contains(point))
                {
                    _drag = true;
                    _dragStart = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);
                    _dragAnchor = AnchorPoint.BottomRight;
                    _dragRect = new RectangleF(_rect.Left, _rect.Top, _rect.Width, _rect.Height);
                }
                else if (rectRotate.Contains(point))
                {
                    _drag = true;
                    _dragStart = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);
                    _dragAnchor = AnchorPoint.Rotation;
                    _dragRect = new RectangleF(_rect.Left, _rect.Top, _rect.Width, _rect.Height);
                    _dragRot = _rectRotation;
                }
                else if (rect.Contains(point))
                {
                    _drag = true;
                    _dragStart = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);
                    _dragAnchor = AnchorPoint.Center;
                    _dragRect = new RectangleF(_rect.Left, _rect.Top, _rect.Width, _rect.Height);
                    _dragStartOffset = new PointF(e.X - _rectPos.X, e.Y - _rectPos.Y);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _drag = false;    
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_drag)
            {
                var mat = new Matrix();

                mat.Translate(_rectPos.X, _rectPos.Y);
                mat.Rotate(_rectRotation);
                mat.Invert();

                var point = mat.TransformPoint(new PointF(e.X, e.Y));

                SizeF deltaSize;
                PointF clamped;

                switch (_dragAnchor)
                {
                    case AnchorPoint.TopLeft:

                        clamped = new PointF(Math.Min(0, point.X), Math.Min(0, point.Y));
                        deltaSize = new SizeF(clamped.X - _dragStart.X, clamped.Y - _dragStart.Y);
                        _rect = new RectangleF(
                            _dragRect.Left + deltaSize.Width,
                            _dragRect.Top + deltaSize.Height,
                            _dragRect.Width - deltaSize.Width,
                            _dragRect.Height - deltaSize.Height);
                        break;

                    case AnchorPoint.TopRight:
                        clamped = new PointF(Math.Max(0, point.X), Math.Min(0, point.Y));
                        deltaSize = new SizeF(clamped.X - _dragStart.X, clamped.Y - _dragStart.Y);
                        _rect = new RectangleF(
                            _dragRect.Left,
                            _dragRect.Top + deltaSize.Height,
                            _dragRect.Width + deltaSize.Width,
                            _dragRect.Height - deltaSize.Height);
                        break;

                    case AnchorPoint.BottomLeft:
                        clamped = new PointF(Math.Min(0, point.X), Math.Max(0, point.Y));
                        deltaSize = new SizeF(clamped.X - _dragStart.X, clamped.Y - _dragStart.Y);
                        _rect = new RectangleF(
                            _dragRect.Left + deltaSize.Width,
                            _dragRect.Top,
                            _dragRect.Width - deltaSize.Width,
                            _dragRect.Height + deltaSize.Height);
                        break;

                    case AnchorPoint.BottomRight:
                        clamped = new PointF(Math.Max(0, point.X), Math.Max(0, point.Y));
                        deltaSize = new SizeF(clamped.X - _dragStart.X, clamped.Y - _dragStart.Y);
                        _rect = new RectangleF(
                            _dragRect.Left,
                            _dragRect.Top,
                            _dragRect.Width + deltaSize.Width,
                            _dragRect.Height + deltaSize.Height);
                        break;

                    case AnchorPoint.Rotation:
                        var vecX = point.X;
                        var vecY = -point.Y;

                        var len = Math.Sqrt(vecX*vecX + vecY*vecY);

                        var normX = vecX / len;
                        var normY = vecY / len;

                        //In rectangles's space, 
                        //compute dot product between, 
                        //Up and mouse-position vector
                        var dotProduct = (0*normX + 1*normY);
                        var angle = Math.Acos(dotProduct);

                        if (point.X < 0)
                            angle = -angle;

                        // Add (delta-radians) to rotation as degrees
                        _rectRotation += (float) ((180/Math.PI)*angle);

                        break;

                    case AnchorPoint.Center:
                        //move this in screen-space
                        _rectPos = new PointF(e.X - _dragStartOffset.X, e.Y - _dragStartOffset.Y);
                        break;
                }

                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

The trick is to move your mouse points into the rectangle's space. This is done by making a matrix with the rectangles point of origin, its rotation and inverting it:

```
var mat = new Matrix();
mat.Translate(_rectPos.X, _rectPos.Y);
mat.Rotate(_rectRotation);
mat.Invert();
```

then you multiply your screen-space points with the inverted matrix to get you a point in the rectangle's space.

```
var point = mat.TransformPoint(new PointF(e.X, e.Y));
```

From there is very simple to do all your operations. i.e. all intersections are point-box tests, and all transformations and scaling are done on an axis-aligned box.

### Example

[image]

### Todo

- separate the code and make reusable
- when you stop dragging, reset the `_rectPos` to the center of the rectangle

Enjoy. :)

Comment: i am checking this and will update you here in a comment. thanks for trying this up for me.

Comment: yeah another hour or so and I'll tidy it all up; it was like a 30 min job. :P

Comment: yeah its messy and thank you.. i am gonna test it in few minutes

Comment: Happy Happy birthday Meirion :)

Comment: Final version (unless you want something else?). hope it helps. :)

Comment: its final :) i am trying to adjust it in my project. thanks again :)