How can I rotate a picturebox with mouse events in c#form?
I have a picturebox in form 1. I try to rotate picturebox with mouse events but I cant. I want to do like https://i.sstatic.net/z1geMiL5.png .
Can you help me how can I rotate.
I did not find anything when I ask to people they say "It is impossible".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-winforms

Does this answer your question? How do I rotate a picture in WinForms

This post is complicated and I do not understand anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154020/re-size-a-rotated-rectangle-using-mouse-drag-in-c-sharp
